# Can't write image data to path in laravel 8 using the Intervention library

Tags: php, laravel

I'm Using Laravel 8 and I'm Facing this error.

> Can't write image data to path (/home/u520518518/domains/dev.peacockindia.in/public_html/public/Backend/Image/Brand/2003012866_Brand-Image_Mobile_jpg)

This is My Code

```
if($request->logo){
    $image = $request->file('logo');
    $img   = rand().'_'.'Brand-Image'.'_'.$request->title.'_'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $loc   = public_path('Backend/Image/Brand/'.$img);
    Image::make($image)->save($loc);
    $brand->logo   = $img;
}
```

Comment: look like permission issue, have you tried write to storage

Comment: Image::make( storage_path().'/Backend/Image/Brand/'.$img)->save(public_path('Backend/Image/Brand/'.$img));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this

```
$loc   = 'Backend/Image/Brand/'.$img;
```

and its worked

Answer (score 1):

```
 $image = $request->file('image');
        $slug = Str::slug($request->name);
        if (isset($image))
        {
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/employee-images'))
            {
                mkdir('storage/uploads/employee-images',0777,true);
            }
            $image->move('storage/uploads/employee-images',$imagename);
        }else{
            $imagename = "default.png";
        }
```